# Dockerfile ADD - Embedded in image or ADDed to container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I have a Dockerfile that use `ADD file-folder/ target-folder/` does the content get added into the `image` or only once you create the `container`?

Is it used `docker build` or `docker run`?

Note: I use a `docker-compose project` but some of the content is `ADDed` in Dockerfile, not as volumes.

Again, the modularity of images (or rather `Dockerfile`) come into question if `ADD` items are embedded into the image.  I fully understand and get the value of `RUN` elements into the `image`, but when I want to add several projects using slightly different `ADD` variants (Dockerfile variants which then gets used in seperate `docker-compose` files).

Comment: The anonymous downvotes :(  Would have been better to either tell me of a duplicate or reason why downvotes were necessary.  No information supplied for the downvotes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a Dockerfile

when you execute `docker build` on a Dockerfile, you create a Docker image.
The files `ADD`ed are indeed baked into the image.

---

Remember:

- `docker build` is for building images.
- `docker run` is for running containers *from* images.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that information, I was searching for ADD page seperately.  I am aware of `docker build` vs `docker run`.  I have now discovered when using `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t tag -f dockerfile.custom.yml`. I am able to read the content of what the image is built - I now see the `ADD` entries.  _Default `docker build` has too much information output for a larger image, and was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The images I created had **alot of content - lists of PHP7.4 modules/Magento 2 setup etc** so I was not sure if `ADD` embedded into image or not from the report information created by Docker build.

*A hint to assist future users that might not be sure:*

For better *readability (docker image build report)* with the added benefit of **faster / optimized image creation compared to the default build**, use

> `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t tag -f file-location/docker-compose.yml`

> The 'flattened' image contents built show you reports in far fewer rows than the default.  This is especially useful for images that use `cached parent images`.
> *Images are smaller the time taken to build is also much faster than not using DOCKER_BUILDKIT.*

Sample output of `DOCKER_BUILDKIT`:

```
  => CACHED [1/8] FROM docker.io/current_timezone/full-supervisord-nginx-proxy:1.00         0.0s
  => [2/8] ADD ./nginx-proxy/supervisord/conf.d/ /etc/supervisor/conf.d/                    0.1s
  => [3/8] ADD ./nginx-proxy/supervisord/scripts/ /etc/supervisor/scripts/                  0.0s
  => [4/8] ADD ./nginx-proxy/nginx/conf.d/proxy.params/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/params/proxy.par  0.0s
  => [5/8] ADD ./nginx-proxy/nginx/sites-available/ /etc/nginx/sites-available/             0.0s
  => [6/8] COPY ./nginx-proxy/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                        0.0s
  => [7/8] RUN chown -R user:user /etc/supervisor     && chmod -R 700 /etc  0.4s
  => [8/8] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                            0.0s
```